# Create and save an object to a table using JPA but have the table name as a parameter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, entity

So I know that if I've an object (lets say `Message` object) properly annotated I can just do:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(databaseName);
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
try {
      transaction.begin();

      Message msg = new Message("Message");
      entityManager.persist(msg);
      transaction.commit();
 }
```

And the table will be created with whatever value there is in `Message` annotation. In this case let's say `Message`'s object has this annotation for the table name:

```
@Table(name = "tableMessage")
```

Therefore, the table `tableMessage` will be created and the `Message` object will be saved into the table `tableMessage`.

My question is, let's say I've a text field where the user will input the name for the table to where he wants to save the Message object (and create the table if it does not exist).

How can I do this? If I knew before hand I could just go to the `Message` class and change it manually but I don't know.

PS; I'm using hibernate as my implementation for the JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Creating and mapping new tables dynamically is not supported by `JPA`. It would need creating new Java classes on the fly and dynamically update the mapping metadata. You can do everything you want with JDBC or native queries.

for more in fo, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649059/java-ee-jpa-way-to-add-new-tables-entities-to-database)